# Adding a class to the previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".disable-hover" )
    .parents( "div" )
        .addClass( "disable-hover" );
    });
</script>
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?4.1.7"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"https://static.jsbin.com","root":"https://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'auto');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

```css
.gift-product-item.disable-hover { display: none; }
.owl-item{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:2px;
}
 


</script>
</body>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div>First div.</div>
</div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="gift-product-item disable-hover">Second</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div>Third</div>
</div>
```

I would like the div containing the .disable-hover class to be hidden along with the previous div with class .owl-item.

Is there such a possibility?

```
jsbin.com/suloyir/edit?html,css,js,output
```

Comment: Please provide some script / html depicting what you have tried, otherwise it will be difficult for people to answer this question.

Comment: The top <script> tag is missing in your example ... is it also missing in your code?

Also, by previous do you mean the parent like the code says.  Or one element in the line before regardless of if it is the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS as below. this will work

```
.gift-product-item.disable-hover,.owl-item.disable-hover { display: none; }
.owl-item{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:2px;
}
```

Comment: in another answer, you can see the output by runscript. hope you are mentioning the parent div as previous div

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this changed code to explain the answer

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".disable-hover" )
    .parents( "div" )
        .addClass( "disable-hover" );
    });
</script>
<script src="https://static.jsbin.com/js/render/edit.js?4.1.7"></script>
<script>jsbinShowEdit && jsbinShowEdit({"static":"https://static.jsbin.com","root":"https://jsbin.com"});</script>
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-1656750-34', 'auto');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

```css
.gift-product-item.disable-hover,.owl-item.disable-hover { display: none; }
.owl-item{
  border:1px solid;
  padding:2px;
}
 


</script>
</body>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div>First div.</div>
</div>
  <div class="owl-item">
    <div class="gift-product-item disable-hover">Second</div>
</div>
<div class="owl-item">
  <div>Third</div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope this was your expectation

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to achieve that with only css or jQuery. With css I'm not aware of the existence of any previous sibiling selector for an element.
If you want use jQuery to hide the div.owl-item that preceedes the div.owl-item containing the div.disable-hover class using jQuery, you could do something like:

```
jQuery( '.disable-hover' ).parent().hide().prev().hide();
```

This will hide both the divs, if you only want to hide the previous div (as one is hidden by css) you can simplify with this:

```
jQuery( '.disable-hover' ).parent().prev().hide();
```

Hope it helps.

**After the post edit**

I see after the edit you're requiring to add a class to the previous div:

```
// This will add the .disable-hover class to the previous div
jQuery( '.disable-hover' ).parent().prev().addClass( 'disable-hover' );

// This will add the .disable-hover class to the div contained in the previous div
jQuery( '.disable-hover' ).parent().prev().find( 'div' ).addClass( 'disable-hover' );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use pure JavaScript:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("disable-hover")
for (const e of elements) {
    if (e.parentNode.className.split(" ").includes("owl-item")) {
        e.parentNode.style.display = "none"
    }
}
```

Comment: This working :)  ,but how to make owl-item the last element?

Comment: @BartoszXxX I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by making owl-item the last element? Any example?

Comment: owl-item has two more divas above it. Your script also works on them. I would like it to apply only to owl-item

Comment: I just updated my answer. Let me know if that's what you are looking for.